# PHP sort multi array

Tags: php

```
 <?php 
   foreach ($model->deadlineFwds(array(
        'order' => 'fl_due_date, returned_date')
      ) as $index => $deadline): 
 ?>
```

Above is the code for my script, im sure somehow it is working, as if i delete it, the order for the display is changed.

So, the problem is when i use this code, it is sorted according to fl_due_date, however the sorting doesn't make the inputs with earliest fl_due_date on the top of the list, yet is is sorted by fl_due_date at the bottom of the list.

I want it to be sorted on the top of the list.

Comment: You're going to need to show mode code than this.

Comment: this isn't clear enough. Show more code to understand what the problem is exactly.